Firebase function stuck in deploying for an hour, can't delete or revert version
My deployment has been stuck in deploying for over 30 minutes. The option to select is greyed out on https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?referrer=search&project=myProject.

It also hangs when I try and delete the function from the CLI even with the --force option.
firebase functions:delete helloWorld
firebase functions:delete helloWorld --force
firebase functions:delete helloWorld --region us-central1
firebase functions:delete helloWorld --region us-central1 --force

Using the delete drop down at : https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myProject/functions makes them disappear from the gui.
I also tried logging out and back into the CLI and updating my CLI.
firebase logout
firebase login
npm update -g firebase-tools

Any suggestions? Either to get me back into production or to avoid these kind of nominal failures.
Update:
After about 45 minutes the deploy finally failed and I was able to delete all of the functions using the delete command.
I started another deploy and got this error after about 10 minutes:
Build failed: Too many concurrent builds, please stagger your deployments.


If you're having a problem with the console or CLI with a message that is not clear and actionable, you should reach out to Firebase support for assistance.
